# How do I change contact record type on the "All Contacts page"? In edit mode there is a lock symbol on this field

Tags: contact, record-type

How do I change contact record type on the "All Contacts page"? In edit mode there is a lock symbol on this field. I only have 2 record types for contacts - Customers and business contacts. The only place I can see to alter the type is when entering a new contact, when you have to choose which type it is on a separate page before you it takes you to the contact details page to enter details. The only way I can see to change the contact record type is to delete it and then re-enter it as the correct type - this seems crazy

Comment: Are you checking this in Classic or Lightning?

Comment: I think it is Lightning